# Making A Verify System For My Discord.JS Bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So guys, I'm not really a beginner with bot programming in discord.js but , I've now seen that when I'm restarting my bot, it can't detect old messsages.

This is my code:

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

    if(reaction.emoji.name == "✅" && reaction.message.channel.id === '793528912751231015') {
    
        try {
            const role = reaction.message.channel.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "『‍♂️』אזרח");
            reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.add(role);
        } catch {
            console.log('Error : can\'t add the role');
        }
      
    }
});
```

The language doesn't matter but the problem is that T tried every method to cache old messages from a specific channel. But I can't really find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the reaction is partial or not using the `<Reaction>.partial` property. If it is partial, then we can call `reaction.fetch();`

Here is an example:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            return console.error("Error fetching reaction", error);
        }
    }
    // Your code here
});
```

You can see the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=partial) for this and [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=partial) is the `fetch()` method. This example code has come from the DJS guide, which can be found [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages)